# How to set Menu bar location in Winforms using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Actually I set `FormBorderStyle = none`. Then I add one panel at the top for adding **minimize,restore and close button**. Now I wants to add **Main Menu** after the panel.

I tried to set the location in winform for main menu. But there is no properties for main menu.

```
private void HomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.Size = new Size(width, height-100);

        HeaderPanel.Location = new Point(0,0);    //minimize,restore,close panel
        HeaderPanel.Size = new Size(width, 20);

        lblClose.Location = new Point(width - 20, 0);
        lblMinimize.Location = new Point(width - 35, 0);

        MainMenu.Location = new Point(0,30); // Menu bar location. Error appear
    }
```

How can I set the location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [MenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip(v=vs.110).aspx). This supersedes `MainMenu` and, because it inherits from `Control`, it has a `Location` property.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code. Because I am new to code in winforms.

Comment: There is a sample in the linked documentation.

Comment: I add the menustrip. Then I tried to change location in properties. But It become 0 again and again. Even I tried by code I set `MainMenuBar.Location = new Point(0, 100);` still It is not assigning

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

Go to **Properties -> Layout  -> Dock = None**..

Then We can move the menu strip wherever we want.